# как запустить файл py из другого файла используя модуль os

Tags: python, windows-10

Как запустить файл py из другого файла используя модуль os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.startfile()` работает как дабл-клик на имени файла в Windows Explorer, другими словами открывает файл той-же программой, которая "привязана" к его расширению. Т.е. файл `-.exe` - `MS EXCEL`, файл `.txt` - блокнотом и т.д. 
Вы это имели ввиду под термином "запустить"?